# Adding an horizontal line in my table

Tags: tables

I would like to add an horizontal line between the end of the first paragraph and the beginning of the second one:

```
\begin{table}[htb]
    \small % \footnotesize
    \begin{tblr}{hlines={blue}, vlines={blue},
                 colspec = {c X[0.8, l] X[1.2, c]},
                 colsep=3pt,
                 row{1}  = {c, font=\bfseries, fg=white, bg=blue},
                 row{even} = {bg=blue!10}
                 }
X  &   Vulnerabilities   \\
x1   &  \textbf{Vuln 1 :} my first parapgraph... 
% \hline is not working...
\newline\textbf{Vuln 2 :} my first parapgraph...  \\
 \end{tblr}
\end{table}
```

Here is a picture to understand what I have versus what I want:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You can not draw horizontal lines in the middle of the cell.
- This MWE replicate what you show for desired result:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
    \small % \footnotesize
\begin{tblr}{hlines={blue}, vlines={blue},
             colspec = {c X[0.8, l] X[1.2, c]},
             colsep  = 3pt,
             row{1}  = {c, font=\bfseries, fg=white, bg=blue},
             row{2-Z} = {bg=blue!10}
                 }
X   &   Vulnerabilities   \\
\SetCell[r=2]{c}    x1  
    &   \textbf{Vuln 1 :} my first parapgraph...    \\
    &   \textbf{Vuln 2 :} my first parapgraph...    \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

or as you show in question:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
    \small % \footnotesize
\begin{tblr}{hlines={blue}, vlines={blue},
             colspec = {c X[0.8, l] X[1.2, c]},
             colsep  = 3pt,
             row{1}  = {c, font=\bfseries, fg=white, bg=blue},
             row{2-Z} = {bg=blue!10}
                 }
X   &   Vulnerabilities   \\
\SetCell[r=2]{h}    x1  % <--- observe "h" as type of cell
    &   \textbf{Vuln 1 :} my first parapgraph...    \\
    &   \textbf{Vuln 2 :} my first parapgraph...    \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very clear, thank you !